# Understanding ibase and obase used

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> Write a command line that takes numbers from variables FT_NBR1, in  ’\"?! base, and FT_NBR2, in mrdoc base, and displays the sum of both in gtaio luSnemf base.

I know the solution is:

```bash
echo $FT_NBR1 + $FT_NBR2 | sed 's/\\/1/g' | sed 's/?/3/g' | sed 's/!/4/g' | sed "s/\'/0/g" | sed "s/\"/2/g" | tr "mrdoc" "01234" | xargs echo "ibase=5; obase=23;" | bc | tr "0123456789ABC" "gtaio luSnemf"
```

I don't understand why ibase=5 and obase=23.

I read about ibase and obase, and I understand this is a base conversion, from base 5 to base 23. Anyone can explain me why 5 and 23. Thank you

Comment: Your question is absolutely NOT C related. I changed the tag.

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The exercise description is a bit weird. A better one would be

> Write a command line that takes numbers from variables FT_NBR1, with numbers represented by the letters "’\"?!", and FT_NBR2, represented by "mrdoc", and displays the sum of both with numbers represented by "gtaio luSnemf".

A shorter answer would be

```bash
echo $FT_NBR1 + $FT_NBR2 | tr "\'\\\\\"\?" "01234" | tr "mrdoc" "01234" | xargs echo "ibase=5; obase=23;" | bc | tr "0123456789ABC" "gtaio luSnemf"
```

Let's take it from the beginning:

`echo $FT_NBR1 + $FT_NBR2` creates the expression using the input strings

`tr "\'\\\\\"\?" "01234"` translates the first input alphabet into numbers

`tr "mrdoc" "01234"` translates the second input alphabet into numbers

`xargs echo "ibase=5; obase=23;"` prepends number base information; the input base is 5 and the output base is 13, **but `obase` must be expressed in the base of `ibase` and 13 in base 5 is 23**.

`bc` does the actual calculation

`tr "0123456789ABC" "gtaio luSnemf"` does the translation into the output alphabet.